# Possible causes of MySQL query bottle necks

Tags: mysql, concurrency

I'm running a MySQL database (InnoDB) running on its own server, with a number of other server's conducting high frequency and long running (approx 5 - 10 seconds per query) querying to the database.

Majority of the queries involves a SELECT statement, followed by either an UPDATE or an INSERT.

I'm seeing significant query bottlenecks building up on the database server.

Initially I thought this might be due to queries locking rows inside tables, creating a queue, however the majority of queries do not interact with the rows created/updated by the other queries.

What other factors I should be considering in order to reduce this bottle neck?

I believe the number of concurrent connections is unlikely to be the cause because I think MySQL can take a relatively large amount (000's).

Comment: You can use `show engine innodb status;` to check for deadlocks. And for memory: in most cases, the bottleneck is the harddrive speed (and, related, not enough memory). Usually, a lot of data is cached in memory (e.g. indexes) to limit disk access to a minumum. A long running query usually means: a) it has to read or write a lot of data and b) (more often) uses a lot of ram to store intermediate data. If memory gets low (because a lot of queries need a lot of memory at the same time), mysql starts to buffer to the harddisk and clears caches, both of which increases slowing down reads/writes.

Comment: So, to summarize: You can try to tweak/check memory related configuration parameters (e.g. buffer sizes, or if you e.g. don't use all your system memory for mysql), or you reorganize your query execution (e.g. one long runner after the other, not in parallel). But the most likely (and actually kinda cheap) solution is to buy more ram. A faster hdd (e.g. ssd, raid) can help too, but ultimately, you try to not have to rely on hdd.